# How can i edit this dataframe to merge two columns dictionaries lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this.

```
ID  Name id2                            name2                  name3
101  A    [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]  [{'e': '4'}, {'f': '5'}]  [{'x': '4'}, {'y': '5'}]
103  B    [{'c': '3'},{'d': '6'}]   [{'g': '7'},{'h': '8'}]   [{'t': '4'}, {'o': '5'}]
```

and I want the output df like this.

```
ID   Name id2                                                                name2
101  A    [{'a': '1','e': '4','x': '4'}, {'b': '2', 'f': '5','y': '5'}}]    [{'e': '4'}, {'f': '5'}]
103  B    [{'c': '3', 'g': '7','t': '4'},{'d': '6', 'h': '8','o': '5'}]    [{'e': '4'}, {'f': '5'}]
```

The Column name 3 will be as it is in the Op I have just removed it from the sample above. The thing is that even if more columns get added, its dictionaries will update in id2 column.
Thanks :)

Comment: `if there is any another column present next after it` could you better explain?

Comment: @yatu you can consider there are only 4 columns present.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisA  you saved me today. :) if you have time could you please explain the code in detail?

Comment: Hey @R.singh I actually added another official solution that's a bit better than using `dict.update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) in a list comprehension:

From the docs...

> A ChainMap groups multiple dicts or other mappings together to create a single, updateable view...

So first we `zip` columns together, then a nested `zip` to get the `dicts`from each column "side-by-side" in a single list. This list is passed to `ChainMap` which joins them into a single `dict`.

**Example**

```
from collections import ChainMap

# Setup    
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [101, 103], 'Name': ['A', 'B'], 'id2': [[{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}], [{'c': '3'}, {'d': '6'}]], 'name2': [[{'e': '4'}, {'f': '5'}], [{'g': '7'}, {'h': '8'}]]})

df['id2'] = [[dict(ChainMap(*x)) for x in zip(i, n)]
             for i, n in zip(df['id2'], df['name2'])]
```

[out]

```
    ID Name                                           id2                     name2
0  101    A  [{'e': '4', 'a': '1'}, {'b': '2', 'f': '5'}]  [{'e': '4'}, {'f': '5'}]
1  103    B  [{'c': '3', 'g': '7'}, {'d': '6', 'h': '8'}]  [{'g': '7'}, {'h': '8'}]
```

---

### Update

A more scalable solution, if you have multiple columns to combine would be to use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) first to extract all the columns that need to be combined:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [101, 103], 'Name': ['A', 'B'], 'id2': [[{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}], [{'c': '3'}, {'d': '6'}]], 'name2': [[{'e': '4'}, {'f': '5'}], [{'g': '7'}, {'h': '8'}]], 'name3': [[{'x': '4'}, {'y': '5'}], [{'t': '4'}, {'o': '5'}]]})

df['id2'] = [[dict(ChainMap(*y)) for y in zip(*x)]
             for x in zip(*df.filter(regex='id2|name').apply(tuple))]
```

[out]

```
    ID Name                                                               id2                     name2                     name3
0  101    A  [{'e': '4', 'x': '4', 'a': '1'}, {'b': '2', 'f': '5', 'y': '5'}]  [{'e': '4'}, {'f': '5'}]  [{'x': '4'}, {'y': '5'}]
1  103    B  [{'c': '3', 't': '4', 'g': '7'}, {'o': '5', 'd': '6', 'h': '8'}]  [{'g': '7'}, {'h': '8'}]  [{'t': '4'}, {'o': '5'}]
```

This is essentially doing the same as above, only we filter to "id" or "name" columns, and combine them all.

Comment: Thank you @Chris if you have time can you please explain this code?

Comment: i have tried this method by you [[(x.update(y)) for x, y in zip(i, n)] for i, n in zip(df2['id2'], df2['name2'])] and this worked like a charm. thanks again Chris

Comment: i have updated the question for a little modification for future purpose, could you please suggest ?

Comment: @R.singh updated solution, should be a bit more scalable if you have multiple "name" columns now

Answer (score 1):

Considering the name of your dataframe is df, try this:

```
i=0
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    df.id2[i][0].update(df.name2[i][0])
    df.id2[i][1].update(df.name2[i][1])
```